# What's difference between mrpt navigation and ros navigation stack?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that MRPT can also do navigation.
What's the difference between them?
What are their advantages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10611/what%27s-difference-between-mrpt-navigation-and-ros-navigation-stack?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From briefly skimming the MRPT website it looks like they're trying to provide a toolkit that helps with many of the common things you'd like to have mobile robots do. Part of what they're providing is a way to have a mobile robot navigate through the world much like the ROS navigation stack. It doesn't look like they have support for ROS yet, though they are working on it, but once they do MRPT will provide another option for running ROS-based navigation on mobile platforms. Which approach to use will likely depend on your specific application and preferences, I'm not sure there'll be a great rule of when to use one over the other.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically I think they are two different frameworks to solve the slam problem. [This book](http://www.mrpt.org/downloads/mrpt-book.pdf) explains the approach used by the mrp toolkit and is an excellent reference. Unfortunately the pkg is under construction.

The Nagivation stack instead use the [Markov](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mir/cadeiras/robmovel/Markov-Localization.pdf) localization method. Another approach is to make good use of the [karto](http://www.ros.org/wiki/karto) pkg, but the benefits depend on the application.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-17**:
So far I know the difference between ros navigation and karto(lightweight). And...when should I use mrpt navigation or ros navigation stack?

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-07-17**:
thanks Eric. Maybe I'm using the wrong words. But seems yes, mrpt should do also path planning. The issue there was nothing to do with Slam but however they "work together".

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
Does mrpt include planning algorithms? I saw SLAM mentioned by mrpt, but ROS navigation is not really trying to do anything with SLAM. The navigation stack is all about path planning and execution with obstacle avoidance. SLAM in ROS is provided by stacks outside of the navigation stack.

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-07-17**:
Navigation stack is a very good start because is easy to install/configure and you learn a lot of slam using it. Maybe if you have a very big and complex environment to navigate on and "little" horse power on board so I think could be better use karto. But again, depends.Have you a specific problem?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-16**:
So in what case I should use ros navigation? or in what case I should use others?